# Read each string in a row_python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a df where column 'elements' looks like this:
[image]

How can I split each word using this as separator "|" then send each word as key avoiding duplicates?
I used this but it's not working:

```
    for row in df.elements.itertuples():
       for l in row.elements.split("|"):
           list_elem.send_keys(l)
```

Comment: [Please don't use images for data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).  It should have seemed easier to copy and paste the text you have on screen into the question than to screenshot the text.

Comment: @MDR I did copy and paste actually but appears as image, I did not used screenshot.

Comment: In any case it still appears as an image so you shouldn't just shrug and leave it.  Copy from the source again, paste into a basic text editor, copy that and then paste into the question.  Additionally, from reading your comment on the suggested answer, you need to explain in detail what "send each word as key" means (may not be obvious if you're talking about Selenium’s `send_keys()` method or not).  If you want a good answer you have to put effort into explaining the issue.

Comment: @MDR thank you, using a basic text editor before pasting its actually a good solution, will do that from now on. Yes,I'm referring to  selenium's send_keys() method, will update the question.

Comment: You can use this text: `{'elements': {0: 'Plastica | plastica | plastic',
  1: 'Metallo | metallo',
  2: 'Acciaio  inossidabile | acciaio inossidabile | acciaio | albero della gomma'}}`

Comment: Do any of the answers on this question help?  Please take the time to upvote and/or mark one you found help (if one was helpful).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'elements': ['Plastica|plastic|plastica', 'Metallo|metallo']})
df2 = df['elements'].str.split("|", expand=True)
df2 = df2.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'elements'})
df2['elements'] = df2['elements'].str.lower()
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['elements'])
df2
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue is that if, for example I send Plastica as key, the next step is to send as key Plastica to another webelement  then I send plastic and again I need to send Plastica and so on. Basically, for each keyword found after the first word, I send that first word each time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please give an example

Answer (score 0):

Modify this as required:

```
#for each row in the frame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #if blank skip it
    if row['elements'] == '':
        continue
    #if '|' isn't in the string skip it too
    elif '|' not in row['elements']:
        continue
    else:
        #split the string into a list by the the '|' char
        l = row['elements'].split('|')
        #remove whitespace from the beginning and end of each item
        l = [x.strip() for x in l]
        #for each item in the list
        for i, item in enumerate(l):
            #if the first item
            if i == 0:
                #send; print for testing
                print(item)
            #if not the first item
            else:
                #send; print (for testing) first and current item; 
                #break this into two lines if required
                print(l[0], item)
```

**Outputs:**

```
Plastica
Plastica plastica
Plastica plastic
Metallo
Metallo metallo
Acciaio inossidabile
Acciaio inossidabile acciaio inossidabile
Acciaio inossidabile acciaio
Acciaio inossidabile albero della gomma
```